# How to fix slow deployment to SQL Server 2014 in an Azure VM from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

When I had a regular server located in my country (Sweden) running SQL Server 2008 the deployment of my SQL Database Project in Visual Studio took about 20 seconds. After I changed to a SQL Server 2014 running on an Azure VM located in California the deployment takes roughly 2 minutes.

[image: Data Tools Operations]

The first step is the one that takes time, that is 'Creating publish preview' which takes 2 minutes.

Is there any way to speed up this process? I still want to deploy through VS and not create a script that I manually have to execute on the SQL server.

Comment: Why California, is there no place closer to select?

Comment: @SAS Yes of course, this is due to a future release in California. But it shouldn't make that enormous difference, right?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

If deployment times are an issue for development then I would use a localdb instance and push your changes to azure every hour/check in/day etc

Cloud db's are great but they slow down development as they are located near you, also your development will grind to a halt if your connection goes down or your db host is migrated etc.